# Programmatically creating links for static pages with next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

For a next.js pages directory that contains a bunch of static pages (not dynamic routes!)…

```
pages/
├── index.tsx
├── SomePage.tsx
├── someOtherPage
│   └── index.tsx
├── someOtherOtherPage
│   └── index.tsx
└── someOtherOtherOtherPage
    └── index.tsx
```

…is it possible to create links at build time, rather than typing all out manually?

I.e.: not this:

```html
// index.js
<ol>
  <li>
    <Link href="/somePage/">Some Page</Link>
  </li>
  <li>
    <Link href="/someOtherPage/">Some Other Page</Link>
  </li>
  …
</ol>
```

…but something comparable to [Gatsby's approach](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/adding-a-list-of-markdown-blog-posts/) that uses Graphql nodes as location props:

```js
// Example Gatsby.js page

const IndexPage = ({
  data: {
    allMarkdownRemark: { edges },
  },
}) => {
  const Posts = edges
    .filter(edge => !!edge.node.frontmatter.date) // You can filter your posts based on some criteria
    .map(edge => <PostLink key={edge.node.id} post={edge.node} />)

  return <div>{Posts}</div>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only way is to  read files at build time using `fs` and  `process.cwd()` inside `getStaticProps`.
Something like this :

```
import { promises as fs } from 'fs'
import path from 'path'

const Test= ({ urls }) => {
    return (
        <ul>
            {
                urls.map(el => <li key={el}>{el}</li>)
            }
        </ul>
    )
}

export async function getStaticProps() {
    const postsDirectory = path.join(process.cwd(), '/pages')
    const filenames = await fs.readdir(postsDirectory)
    return {
        props: {
            urls: filenames,
        },
    }
}

export default Test
```

You can also store page infos (such paths and names) in a database and query the database instead.

Comment: Gracie mille! Just what I was looking for. Just found some [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#reading-files-use-processcwd) on `process.cwd`, which seems to achieve something similar.